# positioning plots and table

Tags: r, plot, gridextra

I would like to plot two histograms and add a table to a pdf file. With the layout function I managed to plot the histograms (plotted them using hist function) where I want them to be but when I used grid.table function from the gridExtra package to add the table the table is laid out on the histograms and I am not able to position them properly. I have tried addtable2plot function but I dont find it visually appealing.

Any thoughts on How do I get around this?

I want my pdf to look like this

```
histogram1 histogram2
t    a    b   l     e
```

Essentially, one row with two columns and another row with just one column. This is what I did.

```
require(gridExtra)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3),2,2,byrow=T),heights=c(1,1))
count_table=table(cut(tab$Longest_OHR,breaks=c(0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00)))
ysize=max(count_table)+1000
hist(tab$Longest_OHR,xlab="OHR longest",ylim=c(0,ysize))

count_table=table(cut(tab$Sum_of_OHR.s,breaks=c(0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00)))
ysize=max(count_table)+1000
hist(tab$Sum_of_OHR.s,xlab="OHR Sum",ylim=c(0,ysize))

tmp <- table(cut(tab$Length_of_Gene.Protein, breaks = c(0,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,1000000000)), cut(tab$Sum_of_OHR.s, breaks = (0:10)/10))
grid.table(tmp)
dev.off()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Ram

Comment: You can't mix base and grid graphics. If you want to use the gridExtra package, you should do everything in grid/ggplot2. There are quite a few answers on SO about histograms using ggplot2 and arranging grobs.

Comment: You need to add some sample data & sample code to this for people to work with; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to combine two `base` plots and a `grid.table` in the same figure.

```
library(gridExtra)

layout(matrix(c(1,0,2,0), 2))
hist(iris$Sepal.Length, col="lightblue")
hist(iris$Sepal.Width, col="lightblue")

pushViewport(viewport(y=.25,height=.5))
grid.table(head(iris), h.even.alpha=1, h.odd.alpha=1,
           v.even.alpha=0.5, v.odd.alpha=1)
```

The coordinates sent to `viewport` are the center of the panel. Too see exactly where its boundaries are you can call `grid.rect()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Backlin. Precisely what I wanted.